# Getting an oauth token from AAD .net core app?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth, azure-active-directory

I will need to pass in an oauth token to a library in order to POST some information in a remote system.

For debugging purposes, I have created a basic app as per the [Azure AD and OpenID Connect tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/)

At this point I am stumped. The documentation is somewhat opaque to a newbie and I have been unable to find relevant examples here and elsewhere.

Comment: See code sample : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at one of the samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code). You need to look for a Core app that calls another API (even Graph - it is also an API), e.g.: [this one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph).